# Security permission check before moving a file into a different machine

Tags: c#, file-io, permissions, io

I have a Log file that I am writing into my local machine.

I want to move this file into a folder on a different machine. Before doing this I want to check whether the user has write access PERMISSION to move this file.

For example, I have to move the file log.text from machine A -
`local_path = C:\Program Files (x86)\UserLogs`
to machine B -
`user_path = D:\history`

Now I have to check whether the user has the permission to move the file into history folder.

```
FileIOPermission f2 = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read | 
+FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, local_path);
f2.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write | FileIOPermissionAccess.Read,
 user_path);                

try
{
    f2.Demand();                 
}
catch (SecurityException s)
{
    MessageBox.Show(s.Message);
}

if (f2.IsUnrestricted())
{
    // code to move the file 
}
else
{
    messagebox.show("Not enough permission to move the file into this folder");
}
```